# Object detection/recognition using matlab

Tags: matlab, object, image-processing, detection, classification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Object recognition system using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088446/object-recognition-system-using-matlab)

I need help to develop an object recognition system. It needs to identify an object in an image by comparing it with an image in an existing database. For example my database may consist of images of cars, buses, cups, etc. If i give a certain image as an input i want the code to check and tell me whether a car(as in the car in the database) can be found to exist in the input image or not. This is strictly to be implemented in matlab. I have tried correlation, image subtraction and a few other algorithms but to no effect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate: [Object recognition system using matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10088446/52738)

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex subject, that is really on the bleeding edge of technology, but let me give you a few pointers to help start things out.

1. Somehow, you need to take into account the different sizes, angles, etc that might be around. A car looks very different if photographed from a few feet away as compared to 50 feet, as would it photographed from the front vs the side.
2. Edge detection algorithms generally work well at pulling the target object's shape away. Take the edges, identify lines in them, and you can try to compare these lines with those from your model.
3. Range to objects really makes a huge difference in building a successful algorithm. If you know the difference from the front of the car to the back, it can make all of the difference in the world.
4. Focus, noise, lighting, etc need to somehow be dealt with, to ensure that the system works well.

All in all, I would recommend taking some image analysis classes, reading several papers on the subject, or at least reading the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_object_recognition), and then starting to work on your project.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have described is sometimes called object category recognition or object class recognition to emphasize that you are not trying to recognize a particular object, but a member of a category such as "car" or "person".

One popular approach for solving this problem is called [Bag of Features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model_in_computer_vision) of "Bag of Words".  If you have access to the Computer Vision System Toolbox for Matlab, it has functions for detecting SURF features, which can be used for this approach.

Also, a better place to ask this question might be [Signal and Image Processing stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).